SQLException when running native image with AgroalDataSource and ClickHouse in native mode Quarkus
I have a Quarkus application that uses AgroalDataSource to connect to a ClickHouse database. The application runs fine when I launch it normally and i can connect to clickhouse and got result, but when I build a native image using GraalVM and run the API, I encounter the following error:
redis-client, resteasy, resteasy-jackson, smallrye-context-propagation, smallrye-health, smallrye-reactive-messaging, smallrye-reactive-messaging-kafka, vertx]
23:46:46 WARN  traceId=, parentId=, spanId=, sampled= [io.ag.pool] (agroal-11) Datasource '<default>': Failed to get service com.clickhouse.client.ClickHouseSslContextProvider, server ClickHouseNode [uri=https hidden url]@-1477137086
java.sql.SQLException: Failed to get service com.clickhouse.client.ClickHouseSslContextProvider, server ClickHouseNode [uri=https hidden url]@-1477137086
    at com.clickhouse.jdbc.SqlExceptionUtils.handle(SqlExceptionUtils.java:85)
    at com.clickhouse.jdbc.SqlExceptionUtils.create(SqlExceptionUtils.java:31)
    at com.clickhouse.jdbc.SqlExceptionUtils.handle(SqlExceptionUtils.java:90)
    at com.clickhouse.jdbc.internal.ClickHouseConnectionImpl.getServerInfo(ClickHouseConnectionImpl.java:93)
    at com.clickhouse.jdbc.internal.ClickHouseConnectionImpl.<init>(ClickHouseConnectionImpl.java:298)
    at com.clickhouse.jdbc.internal.ClickHouseConnectionImpl.<init>(ClickHouseConnectionImpl.java:241)
    at com.clickhouse.jdbc.ClickHouseDriver.connect(ClickHouseDriver.java:145)
    at com.clickhouse.jdbc.ClickHouseDriver.connect(ClickHouseDriver.java:41)
    at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:226)
    at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:536)
    at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:517)
    at java.base@17.0.8/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at io.agroal.pool.util.PriorityScheduledExecutor.beforeExecute(PriorityScheduledExecutor.java:75)
    at java.base@17.0.8/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
    at java.base@17.0.8/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base@17.0.8/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads.threadStartRoutine(PlatformThreads.java:775)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.windows.WindowsPlatformThreads.osThreadStartRoutine(WindowsPlatformThreads.java:178)

Code:
Here is the relevant code snippet:
import io.agroal.api.AgroalDataSource;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

@Path("")
public class ExampleRessource {
    @Inject
    AgroalDataSource dataSource;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getTime() {
        String toReturn=null;
        try (Connection con = dataSource.getConnection();
             PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT name FROM system.databases")) {
            try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();) {
                rs.next();
                toReturn = "Current time: " + rs.getString(1);
                System.out.println(toReturn);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return toReturn;
    }
}

My POM.XML
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
        <compiler-plugin.version>3.11.0</compiler-plugin.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
        <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
        <quarkus.platform.version>3.2.2.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
        <jdbc.clickhouse.version>3.0.1</jdbc.clickhouse.version>
        <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M7</surefire-plugin.version>
        <clickhouse.jdbc.version>0.4.1</clickhouse.jdbc.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>


                <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-config-yaml</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkiverse.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-clickhouse</artifactId>
            <version>${jdbc.clickhouse.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-agroal</artifactId>
        </dependency>

       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.clickhouse</groupId>
            <artifactId>clickhouse-jdbc</artifactId>
            <classifier>http</classifier>
            <version>${clickhouse.jdbc.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>*</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

    </dependencyManagement>

etc...


What I've Tried:

The application runs fine when launched normally.
The native image is generated without any issues.
The error occurs only when running the native image.

Additional Information:

I am using GraalVM 22.3.0 to build the native image.
i tried to run the application with recent graalvm and latest version of quarkus but got same error
The ClickHouse database is accessed over HTTPS, by adding ?ssl=true in the url.

Question:
How can I resolve this SQLException when running the native image? Is there a specific configuration or dependency that I need to include for GraalVM to properly handle the ClickHouse connection?

Hi fares ben, I don't know this application, but it looks like there is a blog here on this error: https://stack.vesocial.com/solution/sql-exception-when-running-native-image-with-agroal-data - I'd start with making sure that the ClickHouse service hostname and port are accessible, and that the SSL certificates are valid. I often would test first with openssl s_client: $ openssl s_client -connect hostname:port - hope this helps

@ThomO'Connor Thank you for your response. I appreciate your suggestions.
I've tried declaring the com.clickhouse.client.ClickHouseSslContextProvider class in the reflection configuration as suggested, and I even attempted to create a Substitution class but unfortunately, it wasn't successful.
for a temporary solution, I'll put the application in the same cluster as clickhouse, and connect only with http.
